# controlling a button in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to control button from fragment xml file in the fragment activity. In other activity we can easily control our button by findviewbyid method and after that we can apply setonclicklistener. But here in fragment how do i access the button and apply onclicklistener method.
**My Fragment.java**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class QuoteTypeFragment extends Fragment {


        public QuoteTypeFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        LinearLayout  typeOne, typeTwo, typeThree, typeFour;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quote_type, container, false);
            return vv;
        }

    }
```

**My Fragment.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3f525e"
        tools:context=".QuoteTypeFragment">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

So here I want to control the submit button in fragment.java. How can I acces the button by findviewbyid or findfragmentbyid. And in fragment.java where do I use that code to access submitbutton.

Comment: Sorry but I search first but didn't find the accurate result so I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in OnCreateView

```
    Button button;

        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                View vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quote_type, container, false);

            button = vv.findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });

             return vv;
            }
```

Comment: what if I want to make my button global where will I initialize the button

Answer (score 0):

In your **QuoteTypeFragment.java**

1) Cast the widget by using the view. (view.findViewById()).

2) Set the onClickistener.

3) Implement View.OnClickListener and the onClick method.

```
public class QuoteTypeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quote_type, container, false);

        Button mSubmitButton = vv.findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
        mSubmitButton.setonClickListener(this);

        return vv;
    }
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.submitbutton:
                // Control the button
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to control button from fragment XML file in the fragment activity.

In your **onCreateView** use these lines,

```
Button button; 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quote_type, container, false);
    button = vv.view.findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
    return vv;
}
```